# Delete a row when I write x in column P. (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Can you help me please. I would like to use this macro to delete whole cells

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
lz = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Rows.Row
For t = lz To 2 Step -1 
    If Cells(t, 1).Value = "x" Then
        Rows(t).delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
Next t
End Sub
```

But my column A is not empty and i must use another column like P (with formular =WENN($F6="next";"x";"")+1 in Column) for this part. I don´t see the solution. Thank you for help.

Comment: Hint: `Cells(Rows.Count, 1)` and `Cells(t, 1).Value` - the `1` refers to the first column. Also note that one can use the column index or letter with `Cells`, so `Cells(t, "P")` is valid.

Comment: OK i only write the number 16 in Cells(t, 16) and not in Cells(Rows.Count, 16). There was the mistake. I use youre example. That's clearer to me than numbers. Thank you so much :)